# clarification on Impersionation step in workflows

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, impersonation

I recently faced some problems with workflows which performed pretty easy actions and I was forced to re-do them under impersonation step.

In a situation where a list allows entries from all (all are contributors) I set up a send email workflow when item is created to send a receipt about the entry. The workflow was not sending the email to the 'created by' user. When I used Impersonation step, it worked.

Why is that? The list is set as all can read but you can only modify your own entry and there is also the approval feature, so when the item is created it is pending.

Can someone explain why I need impersonation step to have the email fired up?

Comment: How is the draft item security configured? Who can see the draft items (pending approval)?

Comment: pending items can be seen by users who can edit items and Create items and edit items that were created by the user

Comment: Just as a test -are you able to check/run the workflow after disabling approval of items

Comment: not immediately but we do want a formality like approved/reject

Comment: you can create a test list separately perhaps? A "Wait for a field to change" (approval status to change to approved/rejected) step might be required keeping your current setup as is. Seems like a case of permissions - remove the item level security and setup the view to show items create by [me] only as an alternative

Comment: i have a test list but even if i find out that it works without impersonation step by removing approval feature, my business will always prefer to keep it and keep the impersonation step

Comment: It was just to troubleshoot the problem - not a proposal to change to the business process :)

Answer (score 2):

Impersonation is the technique where we get the Administrator access even if the current user does not have rights to do some operations like read/write.

Regardless of current user rights it directly uses the system user which have administrator level rights.

[Reference 1-for workflow](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/31/impersonation-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/)

[Reference 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433494/Impersonation-in-SharePoint)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I do not understand why the action 'send email' needs elevated permissions, your pages do not quote 'send email' as example action

Comment: The current user have the rights to send email?

Comment: The current user is contributor.

Comment: As I know Contribute user have the rights for CRUD operations.
So check the email setting/configuration!